# Java - create HashMap from stream using a property as a key

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have a HashMap where id is a key and entity is a value. I need to create a new HashMap with one entity's property as a key and entire entity remains a value. So I wrote:

```
Stream<Link> linkStream = linkMap.values().stream();
HashMap<String, Link> anotherLinkMap = linkStream.collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.getLink(), l -> l));
```

But the compiler says:

```
Required type:
HashMap<String, Link>
Provided:
Map<Object, Object>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) K, U exist so that Map<K, U> conforms to HashMap<String, Link>
```

Yes, it is easy to write it using `for` loop, but I would like to use stream. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change the type of `anotherLinkMap` to `Map` or use the four argument version of  `toMap`.

Comment: are you looking to `Map<String, Link> collect = linkMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Link::getLink, l -> l));`?

Comment: @michalk seems, it helped, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collector you are using returns some implementation of `Map` so either you change the type of `anotherLinkMap` to `Map<String,Link>` or use the four argument version of the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method :

```
HashMap<String, Link> anotherLinkMap = linkStream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Link::getLink, link -> link, (link, link2) -> link, HashMap::new));
```